# Is there a better way to pick the first element of a List in Scala

Tags: list, scala

Currently I use this to pick the first element of a list:

```
   def Get_Read_Key =
   {
      logger.entering (TAG, "Get_Read_Key")

      val Retval = if (Read_Key_Available)
      {
         val Retval = Keystrokes.head

         Keystrokes = Keystrokes.tail

         Retval
      }
      else
      {
         calculator.ui.IKey.No_Key
      } // if

      logger.exiting (TAG, "Get_Read_Key", Retval)
          Retval
   } // Get_Read_Key

   def Read_Key_Available = Keystrokes.size > 0
```

But it looks all kind of clumsy — especially the double ´Retval´. Is there a better way of doing this? Or is it just the price to pay for using an immutable list?

Background: The routine is used on a Unit Test Mock class – return types are set.

Comment: You may benefit returning Option[Keystroke] instead of having a special no-keystroke value,

Comment: As said in the last sentence: This is just the unit test and return values are set by the actual application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're implementing an `Iterator` on a `List`, that's already in the standard library.

```
val it = Keystrokes.iterator
def Read_Key_Available = it.hasNext
def Get_Read_Key = if(it.hasNext) it.next() else calculator.ui.IKey.No_Key
```

Answer (score 7):

The following code will get you the first element of `Keystrokes` list if it's not empty and `calculator.ui.IKey.No_Key` otherwise:

```
Keystrokes.headOption.getOrElse( calculator.ui.IKey.No_Key )
```

P.S. Reassigning `Keystrokes` to a tail is a definite sign of a bad design. Instead you should use the mentioned by *themel* already existing iteration capabilities of a list in your algorithm. Most probably using methods such as `map` or `foreach` will solve your problem.

P.P.S. You've violated several [Scala naming conventions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html):

- variable, value, method and function names begin with lowercase
- `camelCase` is used to delimit words instead of underscore. In fact using underscore for these purposes is greatly discouraged due to Scala having a special treating of that specific character

Answer (score 2):

You can use pattern matching:

```
Keystrokes match {
  case h::t => 
    KeyStrokes = t
    h
  case _ => 
    calculator.ui.IKey.No_key
}
```